# JsonPath filter query syntax

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm trying to write a JsonPath query that selects a specific object based on a condition, but either the syntax fails me or I fail the syntax.

Given the below Json object, how would I select the "Data" object containing Dirk Gently's details based on the fact that he uses the "Stumble" method?

```
{
  "Investigators": [
    {
      "Type": "Legend",
      "Object": {
        "Method": "Investigate",
        "Data": {
          "Name": "Sherlock",
          "Surname": "Holmes"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Type": "Visionary",
      "Object": {
        "Method": "Stumble",
        "Data": {
          "Name": "Dirk",
          "Surname": "Gently"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "Version": 1
}
```

I know that I can get to the Method-field like this:

```
$.Investigators..Object.Method
```

I assumed that something like this would work:

```
  $.Investigators..Object[?(@.Method=="Stumble")].Data
```

I'm testing this using: https://jsonpath.com/ to evaluate the query - and I can't seem to get it right.

Am I trying to do something that is not achievable or am I just making a stupid mistake?

Comment: If you [try your expression here](  $.Investigators..Object[?(@.Method=="Stumble")].Data ), you'll see it works with the Jayway and Gatling implementations.

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting. Thought I was losing my mind for a moment. If you turn this into an answer - I'l gladly mark it as accepted. Your comment did actually solve my problem, since I didn't take into account that multiple implementations might or might  not implement things differently.

Comment: No point losing your mind (or anything else) over it :) See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [this jsonpath online sandbox](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) and try this experssion:

```
 $.Investigators..Object[?(@.Method=="Stumble")].Data
```

using either the Jayway or Gatling implementations, the output will be:

```
[
   {
      "Name" : "Dirk",
      "Surname" : "Gently"
   }
]
```